# How to use tor?

Tags: help

So I have tor or tor browser installed on my PC I have medium security setting on but what now am I safe to search??  I'm new to this whole thing and I've got it on mobile but I don't really know what to do on PC.

Comment: Use "Safest" setting for max anonymity and safety. On a trusted site, it's safe to search with "Safer" or "Standard" setting, if necessary to see content, such as [Tor Metrics map](https://atlas.torproject.org/#map).

Answer (score 0):

If you follow what [The Tor Project says](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en#stayinganonymous), you should be safe. If you're still unsure, browse around their website. If you follow their advice, you should be okay to visit any website you wish (as long as it is legal).